# How to replace a line before a match in linux (RHEL7)

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I want to replace a line which is 2 lines before the match/pattern but this match pattern is also getting repeated for 5 times in file and I want this replacement should happen only before the 5th match. For eg:

Input file

```
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task1111</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task2222</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task3333</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task4444</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
```

Now I want replace "yes" to "no" in the 3rd last line. please remember line "444" is repeated 5 time in file and PSC-Task5555 is also repeated multiple times in entire file.

My requirement is in file, when we find below 2 combination of lines

```
<moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
```

then replace the "yes" to "no" as below:

```
<alarmSpecification active="**no**">
<moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
```

Thanks
Ujjawal

Comment: Welcome! Is it not the 4th line, not the 3rd?

Comment: Please clarify if you're trying to match on the 5th occurrence of `<moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>\n<errorCode>444</errorCode>` (with those specific values), or just trying to update the 5th `<alarmSpecification` line or something else, i.e. tell us what `the match/pattern` actually IS in your question.

Comment: Hi, Situation is like ,I am upgrading a linux server. Post version upgrade, lot of new error codes and corresponding tasks (1111 or 2222 or3333 etc) will get added in alarms.xml file. Now I want to update "active=no" when I find below 2 parameters in consecutive lines.      <moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>.     Please note that this error code (444) and taskID (task111 etc) will be there in alarm.xml many times. So I can not just match either of them and change the active=no. I have to make sure both lines are consecutive then change happen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your xml is properly formed then you could use `xmlstarlet`

```
xmlstarlet edit --update \
    '//alarmSpecification[errorCode=444][moduleId="PSC-Task5555"]/@active' --value "no" file1
```

Output

```
<alarmSpecifications>
  <alarmSpecification active="yes">
    <moduleId>PSC-Task1111</moduleId>
    <errorCode>444</errorCode>
  </alarmSpecification>
  <alarmSpecification active="yes">
    <moduleId>PSC-Task2222</moduleId>
    <errorCode>444</errorCode>
  </alarmSpecification>
  <alarmSpecification active="yes">
    <moduleId>PSC-Task3333</moduleId>
    <errorCode>444</errorCode>
  </alarmSpecification>
  <alarmSpecification active="yes">
    <moduleId>PSC-Task4444</moduleId>
    <errorCode>444</errorCode>
  </alarmSpecification>
  <alarmSpecification active="no">
    <moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
    <errorCode>444</errorCode>
  </alarmSpecification>
</alarmSpecifications>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command and it worked fine

```
g=`awk 'END{print NR}' test.txt `

for ((i=1;i<=$g;i++)); do j=$(($i+3)); sed -n ''$i','$j'p' test.txt| perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"| awk '/444/&&/PSC-Task5555/{gsub("yes","**no**",$0)}1'; i=$j;echo -e "\n"; done| sed "s/> />\n/g"| sed '/^$/d'
```

output

```
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task1111</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task2222</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task3333</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task4444</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="**no**">
<moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
```

Method2: Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
u=[]
l=re.compile(r'444')
e=re.compile(r'PSC-Task5555')
k=open('test.txt','r')
p=k.readlines()
print len(p)

for o in range(0,len(p),4):
    u.append("".join(p[o:o+4]).replace("\n"," "))

for g in u:
    if re.search(l,g) and re.search(e,g):
        print re.sub("yes","**no**",g).replace("> ",">\n").strip()
    else:
        print g.replace("> ",">\n").strip()
```

output

```
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task1111</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task2222</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task3333</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="yes">
<moduleId>PSC-Task4444</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarmSpecification active="**no**">
<moduleId>PSC-Task5555</moduleId>
<errorCode>444</errorCode>
```

Comment: Thanks alot It worked. Thanks Buddy.

Comment: @Ujjawal KIndly upvote my answer